# Create Custom Collection in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

I'm not quite sure how to do this, but I find myself using a list of lists quite often in this particular project. I think I'd like to refactor this into it's own collection. Basically, it's a list of users and their attributes. The object I'm using is a `List<List<String>>`. I think I'd like to make a drop-in replacement that maybe extends `ArrayList` and call it `UserList` or something similar.

Note: my only real goal is to keep from typing `List<List<String>>` everywhere.

What would be the best approach to take with this?

EDIT: Thanks. I guess I knew something could be better. Just couldn't quite put my finger on it. I had initially avoided creating a `User` class because I wasn't sure how I would easily be able to iterate over the attributes.

Comment: If the only goal is to type less, are you sure that it is actually worth it?

Comment: You should favor composition over inheritance. If you really want a more convenient use of the List methods, wrap a list inside one of your custom class. Note that a UserList is really just a List<User> so I'd focus on a User class rather than a UserList class.

Comment: Why do you want to iterate over their attributes? Wouldn't dealing with each attribute individually be better?

Comment: In my case, no. Basically, I'm pulling the user info out of LDAP, and storing it in a smaller, more manageable database (with an option to export to CSV.) So, I need to iterate over all the users and their attributes to do my inserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You shouldn't.

You'll spend a lot more time writing this new class than just typing a few extra characters.

#### If you really want to make a new class.

Why not like this?

```
public class User {

    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    //etc.

    public String getAttribute1() {
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute1(String value) {
        attribute1 = value;
    }

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return attribute2;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(String value) {
        attribute2 = value;
    }

    //etc.
}
```

#### If you *insist* on using nested `List`s.

I suggest creating a wrapper class that would look something like this:

```
public class Users {

    private List<List<String>> twoDList;

    public String get(int x, int y) {
        return twoDList.get(y).get(x);
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, String value) {
        twoDList.set(y, twoDList.get(y).set(x, value));
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: @m4rtin Every time I think I know everything useful about Java... but seriously, thanks for telling me. I thought that ArrayList was a core class.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to create a custom `List<List<String>>` for these requirements.

Create a `User` class to store all the attributes, then create a `List<User>`.

Comment: Yes this is common practice and best approach.